# How do I remap the `tab` key in zsh-autosuggestion to replace the →

Tags: zsh, key-bindings, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

In [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key accepts the suggestion but then also tries providing more suggestions, which is a difference in behaviour from [fish-shell](https://www.fishshell.com).

In fish if you <kbd>Tab</kbd> it completes the word and doesn't offer anything else until you start typing something more (ie suggestions aren't triggered on whitespace).

In zsh-autosuggestions, you can only get this behaviour by using the <kbd>→</kbd> key.

So how can I remap the <kbd>→</kbd> to behave like  <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or alternatively how can I remap <kbd>Tab</kbd> to behave like <kbd>→</kbd>).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[from the docs](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/blob/master/README.md#key-bindings):

```
bindkey '^ ' autosuggest-accept
```

my setting, which binds ctrl+space to accept then execute the suggestion:

```
bindkey '^ ' autosuggest-execute
```